# How to set a timer when using continuous bracket drive mode?

Tags: sony, hdr, self-timer

On the Sony a6000 is there any way to set a timer with the "Auto HDR" mode?  (Also wondering about continuous bracket drive mode).

After searching it appears this option is not available which is quite puzzling.

Is there any way to set a timer with "Auto HDR"?

Here's the manual which does not appear to show how to do this:
http://download.sony-europe.com/pub/manuals/consumer/ILCE6000_HG_EN.pdf

I can, however, use the "Smart Remote" app and snap photos from my iPhone. It's a good work-around but it would be more convenient to have a timer in the camera.

Answer (score 1):

I have never came across a camera where you can set up a timer for bracketed shooting but I think you have a couple options at your hand.

- a6500 supports Sony Play Memories. You can try out installing some apps in your camera and see if any works for you. **Bracket Pro** and **Smart Remote Control** are a couple apps that I think may have the features you need.
- You could buy a cheap wireless (or wired) shutter release remote, set the camera on bracketing and then release the shutter via remote whenever.
- A better option than shutter release would be to use an intervalometer as it would give you a lot more control and options for your photography. I personally would prefer an intervalometer over all other options but I am also a timelapse junkie so...

Comment: Tons of cameras do, just not this one. Nearly all Pentax DSLRs can do it, mid-to-high-range Nikon DSLRs and I've been just using this feature yesterday on a Fuji GFX-50S.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible with the camera.

I tried using "Touchless shutter" but it does not have bracket modes.

Another option is a cheap IR remote from China, it helps a lot.